# SQL Server: Sum values from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum the values from multiple rows.  For example:

**My output is:**

```
ID  Value
---------
1    3
1    4
```

**What I would like to see is:**

```
ID  Value
---------
1   7
```

**This is my code:**

```
SELECT 
   id CASE sum(cast(value as float)) 
   WHEN 0 THEN [other_value] 
   else ISNULL([value] ,'') 
   end  AS 'Value'
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id
```

I saw some solutions online such as I had to include the `GROUP BY` in order to avoid this error:

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

But, still no sum.

**NOTE:**
Values are `varchar`, therefore, I need the `cast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sum a string (even if you cast it)
The query will only work if your ISNULL goes to a 0 or some numeric value

```
SELECT
id, SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(value AS FLOAT) = 0
THEN CAST([other_value] AS FLOAT)
ELSE ISNULL([value], 0) 
END) AS 'Value'
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: If `value` is a char string then that shouldn't work without a cast in the `else` too.

Comment: Ja but by the looks of things, if he has to cast to get the values then the table design is wrong in the first place

I had to design a table to test his query with

    CREATE TABLE Table1 (id INT, value VARCHAR(10), other_value VARCHAR(10))
    INSERT INTO Table1 (id, value, other_value) VALUES (1, 0, 3)
    INSERT INTO Table1 (id, value, other_value) VALUES (1, 4, 0)

Comment: If the table looked like this then the simplified code would work

CREATE TABLE Table2 (id INT, value INT NOT NULL, other_value INT NOT NULL)
    INSERT INTO Table2 (id, value, other_value) VALUES (1, 0, 3)
    INSERT INTO Table2 (id, value, other_value) VALUES (1, 4, 0)

    SELECT
    id, SUM(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN [other_value] ELSE [value] END) AS 'Value'
    FROM Table2
    WHERE id = 1
    GROUP BY id

Answer (score 4):

You just need to `group by` the id column.

```
select id, sum(cast(value as numeric))
from tablename
group by id
```

Edit:

```
SELECT 
id,
sum (
case when cast(value as numeric) = 0 THEN cast([other_value] as numeric) 
else cast(ISNULL([value] ,0) as numeric)
   ) end 
AS totalvalue
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: for some reason if i don't add `group by id, value, other_value` is returning this error: `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` like the query really want me to add `value` and `other_value` inside the `group by`

Comment: are you sure you are using the query in the answer? and is this the full query being run? if not, post the full query

Comment: you may not use aggregate function such as SUM without the group by clause.

Comment: @vkp you mean don't add the `cast` or `case`?

Comment: if that is the table you have (as per the question), you don't need `cast` or `case`

Comment: I need `cast` because the value is `varchar` =/..plus I have to use that this company use, for example i can `add` things but not `delete` anything =/,

Comment: I edit my question instead of `I have` I edit to `my output`.  I hope that can be clear to other users.

Comment: Do you still need to do something with `other_value`? You can sum a `case` expression but you would need to put the `sum()` outside it. (Note: It is valid to use them inside `case` but that's not what you seem to want here.)

Comment: @shawnt00 what do you mean by `sum()` outside?

Comment: `sum(case when a then b else c end)` vs `case when sum(x) ... then y else z end`. The first one is what I mean by "outside".

Comment: @shawnt00 let me try it.

Comment: @shawnt00 `Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.`  didn't work =/

Comment: you should post the full query being used. Also some more sample data from the table so we don't have to guess

Comment: @vkp that is the complete query. =/  I guess that the company that I work for is sucks =/ and really want to give me hard time =/

Comment: @vkp You forget the cast on the second reference to `value`. And I don't think the `isnull()` is really even necessary.

Comment: @vkp the last code from `VenoMpie` works perfectly, however, I will also try your new edit before choosing the right answer.

Comment: @vkp I'm sorry, but your code didn't work.  As I stated before in the comment from `shawnt00` I can't add `sum` outside the `case` because it return an error.  However, +1 =) and I learn some stuff from your code too.  Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is get is the sum per ID of [value] if non-zero otherwise [other_value]... this is what you need:

```
select
    id,
    SUM(coalesce(nullif(cast([value] as float),0), cast([other_value] as float), 0)) [Value]
from table1
group by id
```